# Не подключается jQuery. Не работает jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста, не подключается jQuery.
Весь день возился с этой проблемой,
подключал и через папку и через google не помогло.
Буду благодарен вашым ответам.
Заранее Спасибо!

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
    <title>Заготовка</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function {
            alert('Подключена последняя версия jQuery');
        });
    </script>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <header id = 'hat'>
        <div class = 'mmbd'>
            <span class = 'mainmenubutton'>Увійти 3 рази</span>
        </div>

    </header>
    <span class = 'mainmenubutton'>Увійти</span>

</body>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. `$(document).ready(function() {` - скобочки **()** добавьте. И уберите один из `<script>` тэгов, загружающих jQuery.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Простите за тупой вопрос.